# regex search and replace with sub-loops(?)

Tags: regex, search, loops, replace, dreamweaver

G'day,

I'm new at regex and trying to save time converting rubbish PDF "html" which has replaced all list items with paragraphs. Using Dreamweaver CS6 or notepad++ I'm wonder if I manually add ul tags around the p tags that are supposed to be list items would I then be able to search/replace all paragraphs inside a ul tag with list items.

i've been saving time doing things like:

```
Find: <p>Activity ([^>]*)</p>
Replace: <h2>Activity $1</h2>

Find: <p class="s23">([^>]*)</p>
Replace: <h3>$1</h3>
```

but i don't know if it's possible to loop inside the regex somewhere eg:

```
Find: *loop within ul* <p>([^>]*)</p>
Replace: <li>$1</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at what a regular expression is, you will realize that it is not possible to do flow control like loops with a regex alone. Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

> In computing, a regular expression provides a concise and flexible means to “match” (**specify and recognize**) strings of text, such as particular characters, words, or patterns of characters.

emphasis mine – simply put, a regex is a fancy way to find a string; it either does (it matches), or not. It is not a a set of logical processing instructions with a controllable flow  – i.e. not a program.

However, there are other ways to achieve what you are after using a regex alone, as long as you use an editor that supports “Replace all” (probably a given) as well as [multi-line matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) and [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in its regex engine. Searching for

```
(<ul>)(<p>.*</p>)?<p>([^<])*</p>(<p>.*</p>)?(</ul>)
```

will match **any** `<p></p>` block inside an `<ul></ul>` block by allowing for an arbitrary number of preceding and following `<p></p>` blocks, including 0 of either. Assuming your backreference syntax is `$x` from your code examples, the replacement string would be

```
$1$2<li>$3</li>$4$5
```

– replace all occurences and you should be set.